# Android - iBeacons didRangeBeaconsInRegion

Tags: android, ibeacon-android

Does anyone know if the collection given by the interface RangeNotifier is ordered by approximate distance from the device, with the closest beacons at the beginning of the array like in iOS?

didRangeBeaconsInRegion(java.util.Collection iBeacons, Region region)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, the list is ordered by the time when the iBeacon Bluetooth LE advertisement was detected at the Android device.  This may be inconsistent between each scan cycle (i.e. each call to the RangeNotifier), so you probably want to sort the list yourself if you want a specific order.